# Database mapping to Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, rdbms, solrj

I'm building a Java app using a relational database and I wish to map it's primary data to a Solr index/es. However, I'm not sure how to map the components of a database. At the momement I've mapped a single row cell to a Solr/Lucene Document.

A doc would be something like this (each line is a field):

```
schema: "schemaName"
table: "tableName"
column: "columnName"
row: "rowNumber"
data: "data on schemaName.tableName.columnName.row"
```

This allows me to have a "fixed" Solr `schema.xml`(as far as I know it has to be defined "before" creating indexes). Also dynamic fields doesn't seem to serve my purpose.

What I've found while searching is that a single row is usually mapped to a Solr Document and each column is mapped as a Field. But, how can I add the column names as fields into `schema.xml` (when I don't know the columns a table has)?  Also, I would need the info to be queried as if it was SQL. I.e, search for all rows of a column in a table, etc, etc.

With my current "solution" I can do that kind of queries but I'm worried with performance as I'm new to Solr and I don't know the implications it may have.

So, what do you say about my "solution"? Is there another way map a database to a Solr index concerning the `schema.xml` fields should be set before indexing? I've also "heard" that a table is usually mapped to a index: how could I achieve that?

Maybe I'm just being noob but by the research I did I don't see how I can map a database Row to a Solr Document without messing with `schema.xml` Fields.

I would appreciate any thoughts :) Regards.

Comment: I guess I'll use the "DB row - Solr Document" mapping, where each DB column is a Solr Field. I'll try to use the Solr [Schema API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API).

Comment: Update: I've found schemeless mode. And it does the job. However, it's mapping columns with types as "tlongs". The "tlong" part is right, and Solr guessed it properly, but "tlongs" (meaning it's multivalued) is wrong and prevents me from sorting by such fields. I know for sure those fields aren't multivalued as they are table columns. Is there any way to tell Solr not to set those fields as multivalued?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your table columns in the schema before hand or use dynamic fields and then use the solr DIH to import the data into solr from the database. Select your dynamic fields name in the queries for DIH.

Please go through [Solr DIH for database integration](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)

Comment: I don't know before hand what are the DB columns in order to manually change the schema (I'll try Solr Schema API as I said in the comment I've made on the question, to try to get around it).